# What is the best solution for resolving forgotten/unknown passwords so i don't loose my personal work data?

Tags: passwords, personal-data

Recently, my son accidentally had deleted the Administrator account on my laptop. I already solved that issue by changing the ownership. But in the process, I might have wrong reset my registry. So it comes to the boot loop, when I boot new Windows 10 iso it suddenly has a password for my Account. For years I'm using Windows never once set a password. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: It would be much easier to tell you how to fix your system if you told us how exactly you broke it. Remember that we don't have access to your PC so that we could poke around. We only have the information you provide. (use the [Edit] button)

Comment: You could use a Linux rescue CD to reset your password. See e.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-forgotten-windows-password-with-the-linux-system-rescue-cd/

Comment: (By the way, if you're asking about the _best solution_, it's to restore your system from backup. If you don't have a backup, this is why you should.)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, if System Restore is enabled, is to rollback to a time before
your son deleted the Administrator account.
This would undo the account deletion while avoiding any doubtful registry
manipulations (and undoing them also).

If you encounter future annoyances with Windows after these manipulations,
this is more trouble-shooting that you can do:

- [sfc /scannow and DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)
  (equivalent to a major Windows update)
- [Enable Built-in Elevated Administrator Account](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2969-enable-disable-elevated-administrator-account-windows-10-a.html)
  (not recommended)

In the future, you might consider giving your son a standard user account,
rather than an administrator account.